# How to delete an HTML element

Tags: dom

I have learned that even though if you have removed an element in dom it still exists and can be retrieved if need be which clearly means it was kept in memory. So doesn't it cause load on memory.

How can i delete an Html element if i know i am not going to need it at all. Thus make my app faster and have more space available to me.

Feel free to correct me.
:D

I know method `removeChild();` etc...but that is not what i want. It just How to remove an HTML element using Javascript not How to remove an HTML element using Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element is removed from the dom, the garbage collection will remove it from memory if there are no more reference to it via a javascript object reference

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements can be garbage-collected just like any other object. All you have to do is make sure there's no more references to it.